# Nibernate Mapping to two column identical tables

Tags: c#, sql, database, nhibernate

Is it possible to map 2 tables with identical columns to one C# entity via Nhibernate? I mean, is it possible to use data from two tables just like from one table.

Comment: If the tables have the same column you can use SQLDataAdapter to add data to a single DataTable.  Just use the Fill() method twice without clearing the DataTable.  The Fill() method appends the data.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm right, you just need to manage partitionning with NHibernate. There is no native way without paying it in common usage. I suggest you to credit where credit is due... You can simply configure your database to work with partitions instead of multiple tables.